# Android: How to use SystemUiVisibility or other way to ALWAYS hide navigation(the back, home button)

Tags: android

I want to implement a full-screen video player.

To hide the Actionbar, I use:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Then the Activity has no title(Actionbar).

To hide status bar, I use:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Then the Activity has no status bar, but navigation bar still exists.

So, to hide navigation bar, I use:

```
rootView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Where the rootView is be set to the Activity's ContentView. After I set SystemUiVisibility, the Activity has no navigation bar exactly, but when I touch the screen, the navigation bar is show.

**How should I do to make navigation bar always be hidden?**

More Details:

On Android API 19+, I can use:

```
rootView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

and override onWindowFocusChanged method:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            rootView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }
}
```

After I do that, navigation bar is hidden, even though I touch the screen. **BUT** in the Activity, There are MediaController and VideoView, when I touch the VideoView, the MediaController displays, and navigation bar displays, too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try [YouTubePlayerView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)
, and set the `playVars { playsinline : 0 }`,

then when pressing the play button, it will pop over a full screen video player.